# Para que serve o arquivo com a extensão ".css.map" quando eu compilo um script Sass?

Tags: sass

Eu estou aprendendo a utilizar o Sass. Todo aprendizado está correndo bem.

A única coisa que não entendi ainda é que, toda vez que eu compilo um arquivo `.scss`, ele gera um arquivo com o mesmo  nome, com a extensão `.map`.

Qual é a finalidade desse arquivo `.map` para o Sass?

Exemplo (depois que compilo):

```
 dir/
    meu-css.sass
    meu-css.css
    meu-css.css.map
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Por que utilizam essa ferramenta:

https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/css-preprocessors

Como os arquivos CSS são gerados, editar os arquivos CSS diretamente não é tão útil.

Para pre-processadores que suportam mapas de origem CSS (.css.map), DevTools permite editar seus arquivos de origem(.sass) no painel e visualizar os resultados sem ter que sair DevTools ou atualizar a página.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta, amigo :D

Comment: Bom saber que foi útil ;)